# How to rename table in validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing validations like this:    `validates :name_user, presence:  true` 
But I would like to change the name of the field "name_user" in the message: "column name_user can not be blank" appears "column first name can not be blank"

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers

Comment: Why call a first name column `name_user` and not `first_name` or `forename` in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set up a translation for "name_user" in your locales.  You can change both the name of the field and what the exact wording of the error message should be.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name_user: "First name"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            name_user:
              blank: "is required"
```

You can extend it for additional fields and even other models...

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name_user: "First name"
        surname_user: "Last name"
      department:
        created_year: "Year established"  
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            name_user:
              blank: "is required"
```

Comment: thanks for answering. If I had to do that for several models could I include them all in that same block or would I have to make a block for each one?

Comment: I've modified the answer to show how you'd handle more fields and models.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `message` option for this, as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message) in the Rails guide.

```
validates :name_user, presence: { message: "First name cannot be blank" }
```

Now all your errors will use that strange. You can even make reference to the value that was passed in (as described in the Rails guide).

Comment: Will it work? As far as I know, it will display a message like this "name user first name cannot be blank". It concatenates the column name and the message